# Purpose of Delayed time in handler

Tags: android, multithreading

If I delay `handler` for 5 seconds,

1. will `handler` process all the code inside it during this time?
2. Or it will just wait for 5 seconds to process inside code?

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                //code

                }
            }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will wait 5 seconds before processing the code inside the Runnable. Usually this will be used to repeat a task at regular intervals.